# transferring values to php file thru ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to send a json string and a variable thru ajax call and edit the query in php file,
My code looks like

```
queryData = {
    "data": {
        "data_string": {
            "data": "oil",
            "default_field": "Content"
        }
    }
};
from = 0;
$.ajax({
    url: "/elasticsearch-head/lib/es/queryManipulate.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'dataString',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {
        field: queryData,
        start: this.from
    },
    success: function(data) {
        Dumper.alert(data);
    }
});
```

The PHP file looks like, Ive taken the two values in to variables, I wanna alter the json in php and return the value in the form {"from": $from, "data":{"data_string":{"data":"oil","default_field":"Content"}}}

```
<?php
$testData=$_POST["field"];
$from=$_POST["start"];
?>
```

It should return the query 4 times and each time the value of $from should increment by 10
 Is it possible to do that with ajax and php??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be my solution:

```
function retreiveData(from)
{
    queryData={"data":{"data_string":{"data":"oil","default_field":"Content"}}};
    $.ajax({
        url:"/elasticsearch-head/lib/es/queryManipulate.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'dataString',
        datatype: 'json',
        data: {field : queryData, start : from},
        success:function(data)
        {
            Dumper.alert(data);
            if(from < (4-1)*10)
            {
                retreiveData(from+10);
            }
        }
    });
}
retreiveData(0);
```

This is a recursive function calling itself four times.

EDIT: Or if I misread your question you could use a for-loop on the server side:

```
<?php
$testData=$_POST["field"];
$from=$_POST["start"];
for($i=0; ctype_digit($from) && is_numeric($from) && $i <  4; $i++)
{
    $from+=10;
    //process data on the server side
    //echo $testData; // or whatever
}
?>
```

This would you let your data be processed four times.

Comment: I have to edit the output from php 4 times... thats appending "for" inside json and get the value..

Comment: My function is called once: `receiveData(0)`, it posts your `queryData` to the server and on success you can process your response, instead of `Dumper.alert(data);`. Then the function calls `retreiveData(10)` and so on. Each time you can process the answer, four times. Or would you like to process all your information at once?

Comment: no the method is fine...bt how do I edit the json in php file?

Comment: Do you want to decode the JSON string? Then have a look at `json_decode`, http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php, it depends on what you would like to achieve and which format do you want to use to return the data?

Comment: yes..Im not sure hw to edit the json part... and one more thing if I ad the for loop on server side...do I get each response 1 by one or all at once..

Comment: You would get it all in one response, as only one server-side script is being executed.

Comment: Ive tried the json decode...it returned me some error... the format that I want in return is the one Ive added in question part.. {"from": $from, "data":{"data_string":{"data":"oil","default_field":"Content"}}}

Comment: then its better to add the for loop in ajax call itself

Comment: I guess you need to pass it as a string. Try `queryData='{"data":{"data_string":{"data":"oil","default_field":"Content"}}}';
`. Otherwise, the query data is already interpreted as an object in JavaScript, and errors could come up, when you use `json_decode`. On the server side `json_decode($_POST["field"]);` should return the complete object which you could use to iterate.

Comment: I am taking this value from a text box using jquery.. var queryData=$("#text").val();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13906/discussion-between-birk-and-user1371896)